# UOW + Repository + Autofac load two different DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository-pattern, autofac, unit-of-work

I'm facing an issue today and I'm unable to solve it, I searched a lot and can't get into a solution, please help me if you can.

I'm implementing a MVC application which uses EF + Repository Pattern + Unit Of Work with Autofac as the Dependency Injector.

I was able to work with one DbContext class, but I'm facing a situation where I need to use another DbContext instance (which access another database with another user credentials)

Let me explain better: I have EntityA which comes from database A (and have a DatabaseA_Context class). So I need a EntityB, which comes from database B (with its own DatabaseB_Context class).

When I register they with AutoFac, only the last configured dependency is injected on the GenericRepository implementation.

I've already found articles saying that Autofac overrides the registration with the last value.

I've already found other article that shows if I pass an IEnumerable on the UnitOfWork constructor, I'm able to see all of the registered types for it, but I want a specific one.

Am I clear enough?

My code below:

My controller:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IBaseBLL<EntityA> _aBLL;
    private readonly IBaseBLL<EntityB> _bBll;

    public MyController(IBaseBLL<EntityA> aBLL, IBaseBLL<EntityB> bBLL)
    {
        _aBLL = aBLL;
        _bBLL = bBLL;
    }
}
```

My Business Layer

```
public interface IBaseBLL<T> where T : class
{
    T Select(Expression<Func<T, bool>> predicate);
    T AddT entity);
    void Update(T entity);
    T Delete(T entity);
}

public class BaseBLL<T> : IBaseBLL<T> where T : class
{
    private readonly IUnitOfWork _uow;

    public BaseBLL(IUnitOfWork uow)
    {
        _uow = uow;
    }

    //implementation goes here...
}
```

My UOW implementation

```
public interface IUnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    int SaveChanges();
    IGenericRepository<T> Repository<T>() where T : class;
}

public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
    private readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    private bool disposed = false;
    private Dictionary<Type, object> repositories;


    public UnitOfWork(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        repositories = new Dictionary<Type, object>();
    }

    public IGenericReposity<T> Repository<T>() where T : class
    {
        if (repositories.Keys.Contains(typeof(T)))
            return repositories[typeof(T)] as IGenericReposity<T>;

        IGenericReposity<T> repository = new GenericRepository<T>(_dbContext);
        repositories.Add(typeof(T), repository );
        return repository ;
    }

    public int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _dbContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (!this.disposed)
            if (disposing)
                _dbContext.Dispose();

        this.disposed = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        Dispose(true);
        GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
    }
}
```

My Repository implementation

```
public class GenericRepository<T> : IGenericRepositoryT> where T : class
{
    protected readonly DbContext _dbContext;
    protected IDbSet<T> _dbSet;

    public GenericRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
        _dbSet = _dbContext.Set<T>();
    }

    //implementation goes here...
}
```

My AutoFac registration (in Global.asax file)

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

builder.RegisterType(typeof(DatabaseA_Context)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(DatabaseB_Context)).As(typeof(DbContext)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType(typeof(UnitOfWork)).As(typeof(IUnitOfWork)).InstancePerRequest();
```

Please help

Comment: I am having the same issue like you when working with multiple databases and Autofac. What did you do to solve this? Did you just create 2 dbcontext instances in your autofac or did you do this the same for your unit of work? Each for one dbcontext?

Comment: @Mivaweb use the [WithKey] attribute before the DbContext parameter on your service class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [Named and Keyed Service](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html)

```
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseA_Context>()
       .Named<DbContext>("databaseA")
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<DatabaseB_Context>()
       .Named<DbContext>("databaseB")
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Then you can specify the DbContext you want for a component at registration

```
builder.RegisterType<MyService>()
       .As<IService>()
       .WithParameter((pi, c) => pi.Name == "dbContext", 
                      (pi, c) => c.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("databaseA"))
```

or by using a `IIndex<,>`

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService(IIndex<String, DbContext> dbContexts)
    {
        var databaseA = dbContexts["databaseA"];
    }
}
```

*Autofac* also support specifying named registration with the `WithKeyAttribute`

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService([WithKey("DatabaseA")DbContext dbContext)
    {
    }
}
```

[See the metadata documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/advanced/metadata.html) for more info on how to get the `WithKeyAttribute` set up.

With this solution, `DbContext` won't be registered. If you want a default `DbContext` you can register one like this :

```
builder.Register(c => c.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("databaseA"))
       .As<DbContext>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

You can also use a module that will choose the correct registration based on the name of the argument :

```
public class MyService : IService
{
    public MyService(DbContext dbContextA, DbContext dbContextB)
    {
    }
}
```

To do this you will need to register this *Autofac* Module

```
public class DbContextModule : Module
{
    protected override void AttachToComponentRegistration(
        IComponentRegistry componentRegistry, IComponentRegistration registration)
    {
        registration.Preparing += Registration_Preparing;
    }

    private void Registration_Preparing(Object sender, PreparingEventArgs e)
    {
        Parameter parameter = new ResolvedParameter(
                                (pi, c) => pi.ParameterType == typeof(DbContext),
                                (pi, c) =>
                                {
                                    if (pi.Name.Equals("dbContextA", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        return c.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("databaseA");
                                    }
                                    else if (pi.Name.Equals("dbContextB", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
                                    {
                                        return c.ResolveNamed<DbContext>("databaseB");
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        throw new NotSupportedException($"DbContext not found for '{pi.Name}' parameter name");
                                    }
                                });
        e.Parameters = e.Parameters.Concat(new Parameter[] { parameter });
    }
}
```

and

```
builder.RegisterModule<DbContextModule>()
```

Comment: The last approach solved my problem, thank you for the help!